C# BouncyCastle FIPS Elliptical Curve Encryption/Decryption
I have successfully implemented encryption/decryption/signing for AES, RSA and EC using BouncyCastle NOT in FIPS mode, but the FIPS API is very different than Non-FIPS. Concrete examples are sparse, hence my question here.
My program has the constraint of using the C# BouncyCastle FIPS library (bc-fips-1.0.2). Both RSA and Elliptical Curve encryption/decryption is required. I couldn't find an example of FIPS RSA encryption so used the wrapping example from here (https://downloads.bouncycastle.org/fips-csharp/docs/BCFipsCSharp100.pdf, page 42) to wrap a message, essentially encryption. Here is the RSA wrapping code:
        private ObservableCollection<byte>? RsaEncrypt(ObservableCollection<byte>? keyOC, ObservableCollection<byte>? msgOC)
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[0];

            if (keyOC != null && msgOC != null)
            {
                var msg = msgOC.ToArray();
                var pubKeyBytes = keyOC.ToArray();

                if (pubKeyBytes.Length > 300)
                    // this is NOT a public key!
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Encryption requires a Public key, this looks Private.");
                else
                {
                    var key = new AsymmetricRsaPublicKey(FipsRsa.Alg, pubKeyBytes);

                    // TODO: is this logic correct, using a wrapper?
                    // https://downloads.bouncycastle.org/fips-csharp/docs/BCFipsCSharp100.pdf , page 42

                    try
                    {
                        var provider = (IKeyWrappingService)CryptoServicesRegistrar.CreateService(key);
                        var wrapper = provider.CreateKeyWrapper(FipsRsa.WrapOaep);
                        byte[] cipher = wrapper.Wrap(msg).Collect();
                        result = cipher;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    { System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "FIPS Constraint"); }
                }
            }
            return new ObservableCollection<byte>(result);
        }

Two questions:

Is wrapping, like above, equivalent to encryption?
Is there example code anywhere of FIPS EC encryption/decryption?

